# Dynamic Route resolution in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Consider the following path;

```
/items/:id
```

This denotes a view of a particular item, however, the item types are not known at runtime, and are served as a polymorphic set of objects, for example;

- /items/1 - Item Type A
- /items/2 - Item Type B
- /items/3 - Item Type A
- etc...

Each item might have a different set of child routing depending on the item type, differing in path structure;

```
/items/1/object_in_type_A/:objectId/foo
/items/2/foo/different_path_in_B
```

So far, I have decided to configure the top-level router as a non-terminating route on what is basically a wrapper component. When the wrapper component loads, It requests a model for the item from the service, and from that information determines what type of sub-object it is. From there, it locates the appropriate component, rendering it using `DynamicComponentLoader`. The component then resumes the routing once the appropriate component is loaded.

However, I am having my doubts as to whether this is the right approach, and want to understand the concept of routing in a runtime evaluated scenario like this, or if it is even the right approach to make.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should check out [ngrx/router](https://github.com/ngrx/router), it's designed from the bottom up toward this purpose

Comment: If Items types are different components, then each defines its own sub routes

Comment: I think what I'm trying to figure out is whether a route/URL can be evaluated in stages. Consider the first example, `/items/1/objects/123/foo`.
Is there a way to evaluate `items/1` then once its instantiated, pass on the next route stage, `objects/123/foo`?

Comment: Looking into [this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2/) at the moment, and looks promising. Will report back

Answer (score 0):

In the new router (`>= RC.3`) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-interface.html#!#resetConfig-anchor `resetConfig` can be used

> ```
> router.resetConfig([
>  { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
>    { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
>    { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
>  ] }
> ]);
> ```

This way you can load more data from the server and reconfigure the router at any time.

Lazy loading of components is still work in progress as far as I know.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186 provides an **RC.6** Plunker